# How to handle errors that occur inside an initializer macro?

Tags: rust

I have this piece of code:

```
use std::result::Result;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Addr {
    ip: [u8; 4],
    port: u16
}

trait IntoAddr {
    fn  into(self) -> Addr;
}

impl Addr {
    pub fn  new<T>(args: T) -> Addr
    where T: IntoAddr {
        args.into()
    }

    pub fn  ip(&self) -> [u8; 4] {
        self.ip
    }

    pub fn  port(&self) -> u16 {
        self.port
    }
}

impl IntoAddr for ([u8; 4], u16) {
    fn  into(self) -> Addr {
        Addr {
            self.0,
            self.1
        }
    }
}

impl IntoAddr for ([String; 4], u16) {
    fn  into(self) -> Addr {
        let mut i = -1;

        Addr {
            arr![self.1[++i].parse().unwrap(); 4],
            self.1
        }
    }
}
```

I want to either take a ([u8; 4], u16) or ([String; 4], 16) as parameters of new to initialize my struct Addr, what is the correct way to handle the possible parse error inside `arr!` macro for the string without unwrapping ? Can we put a `match` statement inside the macro?

Comment: "Can we put a match statement inside the macro?" a declarative macro is just a template of code which gets pasted with substitutions as each invocation sites. You can do essentially what you want in them. [Very much including a `match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/macros/mod.rs.html#396-405).

Comment: Not sure why you're coding your own when [`Ipv4Addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html#impl-From%3C%5Bu8%3B%204%5D%3E) already exists though. And `[String;4]` doesn't make much sense, why would you have an array of four heap-allocated strings?

Comment: Your code is not valid Rust code: there should be field names.

Comment: Note that there is not much you can do when you face a failure, since your function doesn't return `Result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initialization may fail, you must return a `Result` (or allow panic with `.unwrap`). Use the `?` syntax to immediately return an `Err` if parsing fails.

```rust
    fn try_from(ip: &[&str; 4], port: u16) -> Result<Addr, ParseIntError> {
        Ok(Addr {
            ip: [
                ip[0].parse()?,
                ip[1].parse()?,
                ip[2].parse()?,
                ip[3].parse()?,
            ],
            port,
        })
    }
```

If you *really* want to use a macro for this, [`seq-macro`](https://crates.io/crates/seq-macro) seems to do the job.

```rust
use seq_macro::seq;
use std::num::ParseIntError;
use std::result::Result;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Addr {
    ip: [u8; 4],
    port: u16,
}

impl Addr {
    fn try_from(ip: &[&str; 4], port: u16) -> Result<Addr, ParseIntError> {
        seq!(N in 0..4 {
            Ok(Addr {
                ip: [ #( ip[N].parse()?, )* ],
                port,
            })
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Addr::try_from(&["1", "23", "45", "67"], 80));
    println!("{:?}", Addr::try_from(&["1", "23", "45", "foo"], 80));
}
```

Output:

```
Ok(Addr { ip: [1, 23, 45, 67], port: 80 })
Err(ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit })
```